# For which $x,y$ does the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^x}{\ln(1+k^y)\ln(1+k^{-y})}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am wondering how to find out for which x,y does this series converge $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^x}{\ln(1+k^y)\ln(1+k^{-y})}$ ?

I have a solution which I dont really understand.

$\ln(1+k^{|y|}) \geqslant |y|\ln k $

$\ln(1+k^{-|y|}) = k^{-|y|}+6(k^{-2|y|})$

and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^p}{\ln k}$ converges if and only if $p<-1$, and by limit comparison test, you get that the first series converges if $-1 \geqslant x+|y|$.

The problem I have is how does one arrive at 
$\ln(1+k^{-|y|}) = k^{-|y|}+6(k^{-2|y|})$, and why is the absolute value of $y$ used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a six (that is, $6$), but an “O”:
$$
\ln(1+k^{-|y|})=k^{-|y|}+\mathcal{O}(k^{-2|y|})
$$
See [“Big O notation” on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). This is the standard Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+t)$ at $t=0$.

This settled, you can notice that the expression doesn't change if you replace $y$ by $-y$ throughout. Your textbook uses this to write
$$
\ln(1+k^y)\ln(1+k^{-y})=\ln(1+k^{|y|})\ln(1+k^{-|y|})
$$

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me! But why bother replacing y by |y| if that doesn't change anything?

Comment: @potete It *does* change something: if $y>0$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty}k^{-y}=0$, but the limit is $\infty$ for $y<0$. With the absolute value you don't have to distinguish cases.